# When denormalizing a database, do I need to keep the parent tables?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

Say I have the following ER diagram:

[image]

To implement the above ER diagram as a normalized database, I would create a `School` table, and a `Student` table, and a `School_has_Student` table (that only contains the `school_id` column and the `student_id` column):

[image]

But let's say that I want to denormalize my database, this means that the `School_has_Student` table must now contain all of the `School` table columns and all of the `Student` table columns:

[image]

Now the `School_has_Student` table contain all of the students and schools data.

So my question is, when denormalizing a database, do I also need to keep the parent tables in the database or can I delete them? so in my example, do I need to keep the `School` table and the `Student` table in the database or can I delete them?

Comment: As far as I know, the 'trick' to denormalization is to find ways to keep the parent table and the denormalized table in sync whilst improving performance. So you should keep the parent tables. I'm no expert on the subject, though, so I'll leave this as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: So proper indexes and views to denormalize the data aren't working?

Comment: @Greg Burghardt I did not ask this question to solve a problem I am having, but rather I am trying to learn about denormalization.

Answer (score 4):

Your second example is indeed denormalized, and the original tables are now redundant – but this is not the only way to denormalize data, and I would venture to say that cases like this are rare. Denormalization is a performance optimization, which means that you do it because you have performance issues. These issues are different from case to case, so the ways to solve them also differ.

Keep in mind that denormalization has a cost. Updating the name of a school is trivial in your first example, but costly in the second one.

I don't think there's much to be gained by putting the `school_name` column in `School_has_Student` - how often do you look up the name of a school, given a student, in bulk? What kind of volume will that type of query reasonably reach? The opposite (looking up the names of all students at a school) is more likely to be taxing, so keeping `student_name` might make sense. Now `Student` is redundant, but `School` is not.

Another example of denormalizing the same original database is to add a `number_of_students` column to the `School` table. This optimizes for a specific type of questions ("How many students does this school have?", "Which school has the most students?", etc.) by removing the need to look at multiple rows in the `School_has_Student` table, but all tables are still necessary for *other* queries.

If students also had genders, you would have to keep the `Student` table since those are not included in the `School_has_Student` table. You might also keep the gender ratio in the `School` table (another denormalization), and now you have no redundant tables.

You can remove redundant tables, but you're not likely to have them.

Answer (score 2):

> ... do I need to keep the School table and the Student table in the database or can I delete them?

As ever, it depends.

As a source for [particular] reports, your denormalised form is reasonable.

For *any* kind of transaction processing (update) work, it is not.

If anything, I would advocate having *both*.
This is exactly what a **View** (or, possibly, a *Materialized* View, depending on your DBMS) can get you.  Both generate the desired "shape" of your denormalised table and both guarantee that this denormalised form will be in step with the the sensibly-updatable, normalised tables.

```
create view SchoolStudentView as 
select ss.school_id 
,      sch.school_name 
,      ss.student_id 
,      stu.student_name 
from       school_students  ss 
inner join schools  sch 
      on   ss.school_id = sch.id 
inner join students  stu 
      on   ss.student_id = stu.id ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite often a denormalised, transformed copy of a database is used (for reporting, analysis etc.) rather than mucking up your actual OLTP database.  It's not updated at the time the "proper" version is, just extracted and rebuilt periodically.  In these cases you don't really have to keep the original as your data is pre-cooked to your requirements.  The original tables are available in staging and only used during the ETL.  It really depends on your use case though.  I'd steer away until you need it and even then don't try and solve every problem in the same way.